# Change the $button_labels of a WP_Customize_*_Control() in the WordPress Customizer

Tags: php, function, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I tried to change the `$button_labels` of a `WP_Customize_Image_Control()` by modifying [its source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_image_control/#source-code), change the instances of the `button_labels` and rename it.

```
class WP_Label_Image_Control extends WP_Customize_Upload_Control {
    public $type = 'image';
    public $mime_type = 'image';

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @since 3.4.0
     * @uses WP_Customize_Upload_Control::__construct()
     *
     * @param WP_Customize_Manager $manager
     * @param string $id
     * @param array  $args
     */
    public function __construct( $manager, $id, $args = array() ) {
        parent::__construct( $manager, $id, $args );

        $this->button_labels = array(
            'select'       => __( 'NEW Select Image' ),
            'change'       => __( 'NEW Change Image' ),
            'remove'       => __( 'NEW Remove' ),
            'default'      => __( 'NEW Default' ),
            'placeholder'  => __( 'NEW No image selected' ),
            'frame_title'  => __( 'NEW Select Image' ),
            'frame_button' => __( 'NEW Choose Image' ),
        );
    }

    // More code here...
}
```

And later use it like this but still, no button label have changed.

```
$wp_customize->add_control(
        new WP_Label_Image_Control(
                $wp_customize,
                'logo',
                array(
                    'label'       => __( 'Label', 'theme-slug' ),
                    'description' => 'Description here..',
                    'section'     => 'section_id',
                    'settings'    => 'setting_id',
                    )
                )
        );
```

I found that when you set the `$type` to a different type like *'upload'* or *'media'*, the button labels will change according to [the `button_labels` set of `WP_Customize_Media_Control()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-control.php#L647). But when you set it to `'image'`, the labels will change according to the `button_labels` of `WP_Customize_Image_Control()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid editing the source.

As a workaround that may provide better control for you in the future (say you want to change the button label to different things in different circumstances...) you could consider javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('CSSID').innerHTML = 'NEW LABEL';
</script>
```

You can get the script into your footer using a simple function in your functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_footer', new_button_labels)
function new_button_labels() {
// the script above
}
```

Later on, if you wanted to use different text for different pages/parts of pages, you could add additional javascript with different CSS selectors to target buttons in different enviorns.

More info here: http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php